# Terms for using QGIS in company?

Tags: qgis, license

We are plannig to use QGIS in our company to reduce software coasts.

Do we have to take permission or make a payment?

Answer (score 7):

The answer is No. 
Qgis is released under the permissive [GPL license](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html), which gives you many rights, including but not limited to

- the freedom to use the software for any purpose,
- the freedom to change the software to suit your needs,
- the freedom to share the software with your friends and neighbors,
- and the freedom to share the changes you make.

There is no cost component in this. The Software is free, in both senses of the term. It is Free as in free beer (free of cost), and Free as in Free speech (You have many freedoms).

Answer (score 5):

You do not need any permission nor do you need to make any payment.

But if you do think that if using QGis helps you save your time and money, you could consider supporting the project through little financial contributions either for things you would like to see in QGis or for speeding up things you believe need further improvement